# Registrer new user from client app and authorize him with Doorkeeper

Tags: devise, doorkeeper

My Rails app is an oauth provider with Doorkeeper. Client registered apps could make API calls to retrieve informations from my service on behalf of user.

What i want to achieve is client app being able to :

- register new user on my app via API dedicated endpoint
- authorize this user and return an authorization code

In one or two calls, it doesn't matter.

Users are managed by Devise. I see how I can create user via Devise Invitable but I don't know how I can authorize this user with Doorkeeper because User must be authenticated before being authorized even with `skip_authorization` config.
I would like some help or just ideas to achieve that. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found a solution in Doorkeeper [issues](https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/issues/284) :

```rb
app = Doorkeeper::Application.where(uid: params[:client_id]).first
access_token = Doorkeeper::AccessToken.create!({
  :application_id     => app.id,
  :resource_owner_id  => @user.id,
  :scopes             => 'all',
  :expires_in         => Doorkeeper.configuration.access_token_expires_in,
  :use_refresh_token  => Doorkeeper.configuration.refresh_token_enabled?
})
@token_response = Doorkeeper::OAuth::TokenResponse.new(access_token)
puts @token_response.body
```

I can use this code in my user signup endpoint to create user and then return access_token.